# Unable to configure rehype-autolink-headings

Tags: javascript, webpack, mdxjs, rehypejs, rehype

This is my webpack config:

```js
// Generated using webpack-cli https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli

import path from "path";
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from "html-webpack-plugin";
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from "mini-css-extract-plugin";
import CopyPlugin from "copy-webpack-plugin";
//@ts-ignore
import rehype from "rehype-autolink-headings";

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV == "production";

const stylesHandler = isProduction
  ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
  : "style-loader";

const config = {
  entry: "./src/index.tsx",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve("./", "build"),
    publicPath: "/",
  },
  devServer: {
    open: true,
    host: "localhost",
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "index.html",
    }),
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [{ from: "public", to: "./" }],
    }),

    // Add your plugins here
    // Learn more about plugins from https://webpack.js.org/configuration/plugins/
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      // `js` and `jsx` files are parsed using `babel`
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"],
      },
      // `ts` and `tsx` files are parsed using `ts-loader`
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        loader: "ts-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.mdx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "@mdx-js/loader",
            /** @type {import('@mdx-js/loader').Options} */
            options: {
              rehypePlugins: [rehype({ behavior: "after" })],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [stylesHandler, "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|png|jpg|gif)$/i,
        type: "asset",
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".jsx", ".js", "..."],
  },
};

export default () => {
  if (isProduction) {
    //@ts-ignore
    config.mode = "production";
    //@ts-ignore
    config.plugins.push(new MiniCssExtractPlugin());
  } else {
    //@ts-ignore
    config.mode = "development";
  }
  return config;
};
```

As you might have noticed, I am using `mdx-js` and `rehype-autolink-headings`.
However using `rehype-autolink-headings` does not affect heading, I mean heading are compiled without links and ID's.
What I am doing wrong ?